# Uploading Nextjs project to Github using Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, commit

here's the problem.

I'm developing a Nextjs web app, it isn't finished yet, to be honest it's still far from finish. I know i had to start a Github project first but since i wasn't sure if i would continue developing i started by doing it locally with no VCS.
Now i think it's time to start using it and i'd like to upload the project i made so far. Problem is, it's too big, (property says 28k elements, 600Mb) and GitHub doesn't allow me to upload it manually (drag and drop folders), is there a way to upload it despite the limits?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you add your node_modules to gitIgnore?

Comment: You mean these lines?

`# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js`